# Authentication - Only HTTPS scheme is allowed

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, windows-runtime

Currently working on an app that is connecting to Azure Mobile Services, and needs to require a Microsoft Account to authenticate.

I have been following this guide:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-users/ Unforunately I have run into this error: **Only https scheme is allowed.** and I am not entirely sure on how to fix it.

Screenshot of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hod9i.png

My code is as follows and comes from the guide listed above.

```
        private async void executiveLoginBtn_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await AuthenticateAsync();
        }

        // Define a member variable for storing the signed-in user. 
        private MobileServiceUser user;

        // Define a method that performs the authentication process
        // using a Facebook sign-in. 
        private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task AuthenticateAsync()
        {
            while (user == null)
            {
                string message;
                try
                {
                    // Change 'MobileService' to the name of your MobileServiceClient instance.
                    // Sign-in using Facebook authentication.
                    user = await App.MobileService
                        .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
                    message =
                        string.Format("You are now signed in - {0}", user.UserId);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    message = "You must log in. Login Required";
                }

                var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
                dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
```

The error also says "WinRT Information: URI Scheme is not https" - so how could I go about making the URI scheme https or otherwise fixing this error when authenticating to Azure Mobile Services?

Comment: I too have seen this. VS2015 Preview. This immediate stack trace is "at Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions options, Uri requestUri, Uri callbackUri)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.AuthenticationBroker.<AuthenticateWithBroker>d__4.MoveNext()"

Comment: The error on my end seems to be because I'm using a local MobileService project with an http://localhost:xxxxx address. Enabling SSL on the MobileService project and using the https:// URL seems to get rid of this specific error, but introduces others. For example, a notice (without stopping execution) that an HttpWebRequestException occurred during application load, and then a FileNotFoundException when I attempt to use AuthenticateAsync().

Comment: Yeah, changing that seems to have fixed it for the authentication part. I haven't encountered those other exceptions you mentioned though. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Great! I went ahead and added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Select the local MobileService project in Solution Explorer.

2) In the Properties window, change SSL Enabled to True.

3) Take note of the SSL URL and use that address to initialize the MobileServiceClient object in your client application.

Comment: I have similar problem as a OP on Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App.

I have enabled the SSL on mobile service, and I point to https://localhost:44300/

However when I try to call LoginAsync, the method hangs indefinitiely

Comment: I had other issues when I tried it as well--it sounds like there may be other configuration issues with the local Mobile Service project I'm not aware of. Sorry I couldn't be more help on that.

Comment: The localhost issue may in fact be related to the network isolation sandboxing for store apps. Which can be worked around as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How I fix the error is as follows:

1. SSL Enabled to True.
2. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-microsoft-authentication/
   **Input to Redirect URL**
3. App.xaml.cs

   public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("**http**://service.azure-mobile.net/", "---------------------");

   Change to

   public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("**https**://service.azure-mobile.net/", "---------------------");